# Rails Routing: How to have controllers in series to respond to same matching path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In my Rails routes.rb file I'm wanting to do something like the following.

```
  get '/:id' => 'pages#show'
  get '/:id' => 'articles#show'
```

So that if a visitor types in

```
http://www.example.com/about-this-site
```

The pages controller in the above example would get first shot at handling it.  Then if not, the next controller in line would get a shot.

REASONs for wanting to do this:

1) I'm trying to port my Wordpress site over without establishing new urls for all my pages and blog posts. As it stands, all of my blog post files and pages are accessed directly off the root uri '/' folder.

2) Because I'm not able to, it's a learning thing for me.  But, I want to do it without a hack.

Answer (score 1):

How about redirecting to the second controller from your first controller?

**in PagesController**

```
def show
  unless Page.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to controller: :articles, action: :show, id: params[:id]
  end
end
```

**in ArticlesController**

```
  def show
    # Handle whatever logic here...
  end
```

**Edit**

If you really don't want to redirect then you can consolidate the logic into a single action:

```
def show
  if Page.find_by(id: params[:id])
    render :show
  elsif Article.find_by(id: params[:id])
    render controller: :articles, action: :show
  else
    # Handle missing case, perhaps a 404?
  end
end
```

However, I'd recommend using a redirect if possible. It's a cleaner solution and keeps your controller code isolated.

Comment: The issue with this is that it would cause the client to reload the page.  When the request comes back into the Rails routes, the first route would try to handle it again.

Comment: Right, you'd have to use a different route name for the second action `get 'articles/:id' => 'articles#show'`, but why is that an issue? It wouldn't cause an infinite redirect, it's not also not a page reload because the first action (`Page#show`) doesn't actually load the page, it just replies with a 301 redirect.

Comment: Hmmm...actually, I was wrong in my comment.  It wouldn't necessarily come back to the same place.  But, it wouldn't be the same url.  It would get sent back to the system as something like http://www.example.com/articles/about-this-site

Comment: Right, but that's the point of a 301 redirect. SEO spiders will cache the page from the `example.com/about-this-site`. The only other alternative is to merge the logic into a single action.

Comment: I've updated my answer for the case with no redirect.

Comment: I was kind of hoping there might be a way to respond to a routing exception and pass the request on to the next controller in line.  But, I have found no examples of this.  Ordinarily I would just stick to 'The Rails Way' and keep my controllers simply named with '/pages/*' and '/articles/*'....but it seems like a not so difficult solution avoiding a 301 is nearby.  I really appreciate your time thinking about this for me.

Comment: ah!  I'll have to try that.  My last comment overlapped yours.  I'll take your revised answer into consideration and try it.  If it works, I'll give you credit.   Thanks

Comment: I tried using the revised answer you provided Anthony.  It does work.  However, it changes the url in address bar.  I suppose if this is the only place it gets changed, then this wouldn't be so bad. It's just something I will have to deal with, i guess.